# Apply :before :after depending on :first-child and :last-child

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to create a vertical timeline, with circle along a thin rectangular line where the user can click to display more info.

My approach is to have :before and :after for each circle (span) that extends a rectangular line above and below the button. But for the first (top) element in my list/timeline, I only want to apply :after so the line extends below the first circle. And vice-versa with the last circle.

**html**:

```
<ul
  class="menu">
  <li>
    <a
      @click="onClick">
      <div class="text-container">
        <p>AAA</p>
        <p>AAA</p>
      </div>
      <span></span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a
      @click="onClick">
      <div class="text-container">
        <p>BBB</p>
        <p>BBB</p>
      </div>
      <span></span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a
      @click="onClick">
      <div class="text-container">
        <p>CCC</p>
        <p>CCC</p>
      </div>
      <span></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Sass**:

```
  span
  span::before
    content: ""
    position: absolute
    right: 22px
    bottom: 25px
    height: 75px
    width: 6px
    background-color: lightgrey
  span::after
    content: ""
    position: absolute
    right: 22px
    height: 75px
    width: 6px
    background-color: lightgrey

  span:first-child
  span::after
    content: ""
    position: absolute
    right: 22px
    height: 75px
    width: 6px
    background-color: lightgrey

  span:last-child
  span::before
    content: ""
    position: absolute
    right: 22px
    bottom: 25px
    height: 75px
    width: 6px
    background-color: lightgrey
```

Comment: `button:first-of-type:before{display: none;}` does not work? (and vice-versa)

Comment: @PIIANTOM I've added my html for reference. Your suggestion didn't work, because of how the button is nested?

Comment: i wonder, why to put a button tag inside and "a" tag?,

Comment: @Teobis the `button` tag is what I used when experimenting, it's a circle and I can replace that with a `span`

Comment: @Teobis I've revised the code to use `span` instead of `button`

Comment: So, your iterative container elements are `<li>`. Which gives `li:first-of-type span:before{display: none;}`

Comment: Also, on your css, no pseudo element has a display property, so everyone is invisible